# Read .daq (Data Acquisition Toolbox for Matlab) file format in python

Tags: python, matlab, file-io

Anyone know of a way to read in .daq files generated with the Matlab Data Acquisition Toolbox in python?  Alternatively, a simple way (using only open-source software) to convert the files to csv or .mat files which can be read by python would be ok.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you have solved this by now or not, but you can generate .mat files from the .daq files easily in matlab using daqread. In the command window:

```
Data = daqread(mydata.daq);
cd(saveDir)
save('Data','Data')
```

The Data variable is a .mat file. This can easily be added to a file directory scanning function. Reading into python is also straightforward using the scipy module. From the interpreter for example:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
data = loadmat('Data.mat')
```

There may also be a .daq loading submodule somewhere in scipy, but you would have to look.

Hope this helps!